# Mage_tax_Helper_Data not found on Mage.php

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

When clicking through to the "add to cart" it's not showing the correct information.
When switched to the standard theme all works fine.
We are also getting this error at the base of the code.

```
**Fatal error:** Class 'Mage_‘tax’_Helper_Data' not found in <b>/homepages/15/d213158410/htdocs/designerchocolates/app/Mage.php</b> on line <b>547</b>
```

Comment: `'Mage_‘tax’_Helper_Data'` don't you think there is something wrong with `tax`?

Answer (score 3):

As ravi said, there is something damn wrong. I would search for 'tax' in your code.

If you don't find anything check the `exception.log`, there should be a stack trace.

And as always, read the debugging tutorial: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have in one of the files this:

```
 Mage::helper('‘tax’')->... 
 //or 
 $this->helper('‘tax’')->...
```

There is some strange character wrapping the `tax` text somewhere.
If you say that on the default theme it works fine, I would start looking in your theme files.